# Google calendar api usage limit

Tags: google-calendar-api

for the past 2 days, we receive this error for almost all calls to google calendar api :

```
{"domain"=>"usageLimits",
"reason"=>"quotaExceeded",
"message"=>"Calendar usage limits exceeded."}],
 "code"=>403,
"message"=>"Calendar usage limits exceeded."
```

We checked all our quota on google console and everything looks good.
There is no way for us to find out where is the problem about the usage limit.

The project id is : 338879375920

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

This limit appears in Google's [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded). The problem is not related to the quotas you are able to see in the project from the GCP console but to the "protection" limits that Google hast set up in general for their service to be used.

The error pretty much means that you are making too many requests in a short period of time and their server is protecting itself by showing you this error. This can be resolved by implementing exponential backoff in your code. The way to implement this is completely up to you and any language that you are currently using for your project, but it basically involves just retrying the same request again only adding wait times each time it fails since these limits can not be increased.

References:

- [403: Calendar usage limits exceeded](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded)
- [Exponential backoff algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/retry-strategy#exponential-backoff)
- [Handle API errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors)

Comment: After many improvements, the issue still persists (we added exponential backoff and « quotaUser » parameter on each api request as recommanded here : https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/quota). Then we discovered the issue was only related to the event attendees, once we removed them, we had 0 error and was able to create events as much as we want.  If we add attendees it will break with the error 403.  I saw many posts concerning this issue on google support but I was unable to find a final solution